# how to test if a post goes to the correct place in django

Tags: django, unit-testing

I have the following test case:

```
def test_login(self):
        """Login with user is successful"""
        c = Client()
        response = c.post('/login/', {'username': 'john', 'password': 'smith'})
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

How do I assert that the response went to the correct page/view/url ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [assertRedirects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/testing/overview/#django.test.SimpleTestCase.assertRedirects) assert.

> Asserts that the response return a status_code redirect status, it
>   redirected to expected_url (including any GET data), and the final
>   page was received with target_status_code. If your request used the
>   follow argument, the expected_url and target_status_code will be the
>   url and status code for the final point of the redirect chain.